# UITableView, uisplitviewcontroller - a way to manage detailview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

i'm trying to make my "menu" system work in swift as i had in ObjC.

so far i constructed this

this is in my `detailViewContainerController`

```
var initial : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var foesteTid : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FoersteTid", bundle: nil)

var vc0:UIViewController = UIViewController()
var vc1:UIViewController = UIViewController()
var vc2:UIViewController = UIViewController()
var vc3:UIViewController = UIViewController()
var topController: UIViewController = UIViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.configureView()

        self.vc0 = initial.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initial") as DetailViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(self.vc0)
        self.vc1 = initial.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("startSide") as DetailViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(self.vc1)

        self.vc2 = foesteTid.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("udstyr") as DetailViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(self.vc2)

}

func initialSite(viewID: Int) -> () {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    let dataValue: AnyObject? = data?.valueForKey("navn")
    var start: String?

    switch viewID {
    case 0:
        viewController = self.vc0
        start = "Velkommen til \(dataValue)'s  Bog"
        println("data fra detailViewContainerController dataValue \(dataValue)")
    case 1:
        viewController = self.vc1
        start = "\(dataValue)'s  Bog, start-side"
        println("data fra detailViewContainerController dataValue2 \(dataValue)")
    default:
        break;
    }

    self.navigationItem.title = start!
    self.showChildViewController(viewController!)
}
```

This is where i think my problem is, as there's nothing on the screen, when ever i select a item in the `UITableView`

```
func showChildViewController(content: UIViewController){
        if(topController != content) {
            content.view.frame = self.view.frame
            content.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
            content.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.addSubview(content.view)
            content.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
            content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            topController = content;
    }
}
```

in my `hovedMenu` UITableview I have this

```
var dvcc = detailViewContainerController()
var data: AnyObject?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    if let row = indexPath?.row {

        dvcc.data = data
        self.dvcc.initialSite(Int())

    }

}
```

This is what it looks like in the iPad simulator!

[image: Main Menu + detail view]
[image: after selection of the main item on the uitableview from the main menu]
i had it running in ObjC when almost same code... so i dont understand why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar a few days back and have managed to do it using Master Child Template of XCode 6 and then using segues and then calling performSegueWithIdentifier from tableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Please check my [blog post](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views/) about it, it contains link to the code as well. May be it will be of help to you.

However I see that you are trying to do everything programmatically rather than relying on Storyboard and Segues. Is there any reason behind it? Your code doesn't look standard way to do things atleast with latest iOS8 SDK. I am sure if you create viewcontrollers in Storyboard and setup Segues appropriately, you should be able to easily achieve what you want.

May be checkout my [blog-post](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views/) and code and see if it's of any use to you? Let me know if you don't understand any part of the code.